# Does Microsoft still make a Wireless Xbox 360 Receiver for the PC?

Tags: pc, controllers

I'm sure I read somewhere that Microsoft have stopped producing Wireless Xbox 360 Receivers for PCs, but I can't remember where.

For anyone confused, I'm referring to [these things](http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Hardware/Controllers/Pages/XboxWirelessGamingReceiverforWindows.aspx/):

[image: Wireless USB receiver for PC use of Xbox 360 controllers]

I've searched around the internet but the only place I could find something similar was on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000HZFCT2/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2)

But the reviews seem to agree that it's actually a fake, and not actually manufactured by Microsoft.

Does Microsoft still manufacture, sell (and support) these things?

Comment: Withdrew my answer in light of your link (end of this comment).  Looks like the controller still works with Windows 7 if you have the receiver but the dongle is no longer being manufactured. http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Hardware/Controllers/Pages/XboxWirelessGamingReceiverforWindows.aspx/

Comment: I edited the title, because that picture is of a receiver, not a controller.

Comment: Why the downvotes, I wonder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for Windows](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/Xbox-360-Wireless-Controller-for-Windows-with-PC-USB-Adapter/productID.270981700), it comes with the wireless USB receiver. Once you have one of those you can use any Xbox 360 controller with it. After my Xbox 360 died I bought one of those controllers (basically just to get the receiver) and my two existing 360 controllers work with it too. Microsoft used to sell the USB receiver dongle separately but no longer.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is now broken. It does seem the receiver is no longer being made.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I updated the link. MS is still selling the controller + receiver bundle. I don't believe they sell them separately.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Wonderful, thanks! I wish MS would try and keep things in one place for longer.

Comment: You can get it on Amazon as well: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Xbox-Wireless-Controller-Windows/dp/B004QRKWKQ